# Error in uwp open sticky notes app with uri

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10

I want to open sticky notes app from a uwp app using the UriScheme and according to [reservered uris](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/reserved-uri-scheme-names) I should be able to do that with following code:

```
 Uri uriContoso = new Uri($"stickynotes");
 var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriContoso);
```

but instead it says invalid uri.

**Update**

Now I am using a colon at the end like "stickynotes:" and it is a valid Uri but still it cant find the sticky notes app of windows 10 to launch. I need to open the default windows 10 app sticky notes.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `Uri uriContoso = new Uri($"stickynotes://");` ?

Comment: yeah tried that as well, doesnt work.@AdamMcMahon

Comment: Yeah, I can see your issue now. I'm able to open OneNote and Outlook with their URI's but Microsoft's Sticky Notes URI doesn't appear to be correct. I tried with `ms-stickynotes:` and `sticky-notes:` also and got the same result.

Comment: do you mean sticky notes might not have a valid uri at all?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.

Answer (score 0):

You must format it as an actual `Uri`:

```
Uri uriContoso = new Uri($"stickynotes:");
```

Note the additional colon `:` character at the end. This will make it a proper custom URI protocol and the `Uri` constructor will be able to parse it.

Comment: tht was helpful , please see the update in the question

Comment: Actually the `stickynotes:` URI is reserved but Microsoft Sticky Notes don't support it yet. A bit of a sticky situation :-D ...

Comment: Unfortunately it means you won't be able to launch the app using the URI